# position spheres along a bezier curve

Tags: math, opengl, bezier

I am trying a couple of tutorials from http://nehe.gamedev.net, in order to learn openGL programming, I would like to position spheres along a Bezier curve such that they appear as a string of pearls. how can I position such spheres along the curve. I am drawing the curve using de Casteljau's algorithm and hence can get the XYZ points on the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your spheres are small enough relative to the overall length of the Bezier curve, you can just position your spheres at even intervals to get an appearance similar to a string of pearls. (If the spheres are relatively large then you'll have to start worrying about sphere overlap more -- not an easy problem, and probably not very instructive for learning OpenGL.)

The parameter value `t` of a Bezier curve varies from `0` to `1`. To evaluate your Bezier curve at 10 locations (the ends and eight interior points) you can do something like this:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i )
{
    double t = i / 9.0;
    double x, y;
    EvalBezier( t, x, y );
    DrawSphere( x, y, radius );
}
```

Where `EvalBezier( t, x, y )` fills in `(x,y)` for a given `t`. Just pick `radius` to give you a pleasing result. If you want to try to pick `radius` automatically, just use half the minimum distance from the point `i` to points `i-1` and `i+1` as a rough estimate. If you do this, remember to handle the end points specially, using either only the next or previous points (whichever you have).